# Angularjs : variable scope showing old value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am storing userId in loginUser function and after that use that
userId in getData function but still I get undefined value.

Also, please suggest some reference Regarding Scope in AngularJs.

```
myModule.controller("loginController",function($scope,$http){
$scope.userId; //define userId

$scope.token;   

$scope.loginUser = function ()
            {
                $http.post(
                    'http://localhost:3000/museum/login',
                    {"email":$scope.username , "password":$scope.password}
                )
                .then(function(response){
                    if(response.status == 200 )
                    {
                        $scope.token = response.data.token;
                        $scope.userId = response.data.userId; //change Value of userId
                        alert ("Login Successful" + $scope.userId);
                        window.open("updateinfo.html","_self");
                    }
                   else{
                           alert ("Login Fail");    
                       }

                });
            };


 $scope.getData = function()
    {
        console.log("Function Called " +$scope.userId); //using userId

        $http.get(
                  'http://localhost:3000/museum/museumDetail/'+$scope.userId,
                  {}
                 )
                 .then(function(response)
                 {
                   console.log(response.data);
                 });
       };
 });
```

Comment: Where are you calling the functions? I think the problem could be that when you call the getData function the http request in the loginUser function could have not finished yet. Using a Promise should do the trick.

Comment: Did you check the response of your "loginUser" function? are you getting any value here "$scope.userId = response.data.userId; " ?

Comment: The `window.open` statement loads a new instance which will not retain scope values

Comment: For information on scopes, see [AngularJS Develooer Guide - scopes](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#).

Comment: @Shaheryar.Akram yes i am getting userid and token from server . but i redirect page after that so i am not able to use that updated userid

Comment: please give me some suggestion . is it right way to store logged in userId at server side in place of js file ?

Comment: okay there's a workaround for it. You can use $scope.$root for this. It adds the data to the root of your scope which is accessible across the controllers (not an appreciated way to do this though ). sorry for being late at replying